# VBA passing sheets as parameter to macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel `Sub` as follows

```
Sub btnToCsvASIN()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ds, Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ds = Sheet2
    
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Add
    Set Ws = Wb.ActiveSheet
    
    Ds.Range("A2:I100").Copy Ws.Range("A1")
    
    Dim pKey, pId As String       
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Uploader.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Wb.Close
End Sub
```

I want to make this function generic so that no matter what the Sheet number is, it works.

So, I tried the following and other syntax also:

```
Function btnToCsvASIN(SheetNum as String)
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ds, Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ds = SheetNum
    
......
End Sub
```

My goal is to make following kind of generic function call:

```
btnToCsvASIN(Sheet1)
btnToCsvASIN(Sheet23)
```

I have been unable to make this work.

I call this `Sub` currently from within another macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Range To New Workbook

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TESTbtnToCsvASIN()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    btnToCsvASIN ws
    ' Or using code name:
    'btnToCsvASIN Sheet1
End Sub

Sub btnToCsvASIN(ws As Worksheet)
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Workbooks.Add
            ws.Range("A2:I100").Copy .ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Uploader", FileFormat:=xlCSV
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            '.FollowHyperlink .Path
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```